How to create an horizontal scroll for my images using MarkDown
I'm currently working on creating a website portfolio to display my school projects. I am using GitHub Jekyll pages as the engine for my website.
On one of the web-pages, I plan on using horizontal scrolling for my images, because they are a lot. The file I'm coding on is a markdown file (.md).
Here is a snippet of  my code:
<div style="overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;">
    <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_2/pic_1.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_2/pic_2.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_3/pic_3.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_2/pic_4.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
        <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_2/pic_5.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm mt-3 mt-md-0">
        {% include figure.liquid loading="eager" path="assets/img/DS_6306_Project_2/pic_6.png" title="example image" class="img-fluid rounded z-depth-1" %}
    </div>
</div>

The main logic is that, its supposed to access a couple pictures, and display them in an horizontal row row, then the user can view them by scrolling through the images. An example is the one shown in the w3schools page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_gallery_scroll.asp.
My issue is that the, images are displayed vertically, and most of the images don't load properly. I attached the output to the page.
Web design is not my area of expertise, I've just been getting by on tutorials I see on the internet.
I've tried different ways to fix it like using an HTML or CSS (markdown doesn't recognise it, or I'm doing it wrong).
